# Invalid auth/bad request. Magento rest api

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I followed http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html

I am able to login to "My first application" with admin.

But not with customer.

I got `$_SESSION` like

```
Array
(
    [secret] => 7664a04e54256c135a18b313a9d06872
    [state] => 2
    [token] => fc5be1e6d0cd1cde0ed614281b61894f
)
```

I got error in this line

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

Saying that

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 500, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

Service temporary unavailable

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you should to add "'Accept' => 'application/json'" or 'Accept' =>  */*. So

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

should to be

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));
```

or

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => */*));
```

Comment: omg, you saved my  day !